# runn query in spring api

Tags: java, spring, swagger-editor

Hello stackoverflow team,

Im trying to calculate the conso duration of a given cod. and was getting error saying that id_client was not found in the resultSet. Does anyone knows how to fix it please?

The code below contains the 3 different parts: 
model, repository and the Controller.

in my D1 model:

```
import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity(name = "tmp.c1")
@Table(name = "c1", schema = "tmp")
public class D1 {

  @Id
  @Column(name = "id_client")
  private BigDecimal id_contrats;
  @Column(name = "cod")
  private BigDecimal cod;
  @Column(name = "name_client")
  private OffsetDateTime dat;
  @Column(name = "phone_client")
  private long phone_client;
  @Column(name = "funct")
  private string funct;
  @Column(name = "beg_consu")
  private OffsetDateTime beg_consu;
  @Column(name = "end_consu")
  private OffsetDateTime end_consu;

}
```

In D1Repository

```
import java.math.BigDecimal;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import java.util.Date;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository;
import org.springframework.data.repository.query.Param;
import io.A1.B1.api.P1.data.model.D1;

public interface D1Repository  {

  @Query(value = "SELECT (end_consu - beg_consu) FROM #{#entityName}" )
  T getConso(@Param("cod") BigDecimal cod);

}



}
```

Comment: Does your code compile?  Can you provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Thank you @AlexRudenko for your response. Original post edited .

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to extend your interface:

```
...
public interface D1Repository extends JpaRepository<D1, BigDecimal> {

    @Query(value = "SELECT (end_consu - beg_consu) FROM #{#entityName}" )
    T getConso(@Param("cod") BigDecimal cod);

}
...
```

And as a recommendation it would be better to use long instead of bigdecimal as the indetifier value. It is more efficient to use the smallest value capable of encompassing the largest possible value. You wouldn't use a tank to carry a liter of water right?

Best regards.